# Get gdb binary for BusyBox under i386 architecture

Tags: c, gdb, embedded, busybox

Where i can get binary file of GDB debugger for BusyBox under i386 architecture. I tried to build it from source, but unsuccessful. When i run gdb on my controller - all normal, but when i start debug simple hello world c application i have the segmentation fault. I think that when i set built configuration of gdb - made mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDB "for Busybox"? Busybox is an application (or set of applications), not an OS. Do you mean a uClibc-linked GDB (which is perhaps mildly related, or perhaps not, but definitely not what you said)? Or what? If you just mean any static-linked GDB binary you can move from one Linux-i386 system to another without needing a whole ecosystem of libs, just build your own with `CFLAGS=-static` on any Linux-i386 desktop system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no BusyBox `gdb` command.

Check section *"Commands"* in:

http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

for the available Busybox commands.